# Store value into string array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I wanted to store a value from a string array to another string array. But I get "NullPointerException" error with the code below. "imagesSelected" is a string array stored with values inside. But when i wanted to move it into another string array after substring, I get error. I believed is because of the last line of code. I'm not sure how to make it work.

```
String[] imageLocation;

        if(imagesSelected.length >0){
        for(int i=0;i<imagesSelected.length;i++){
            int start = imagesSelected[i].indexOf("WB/");
            imageLocation[i] = imagesSelected[i].substring(start + 3);
        }
        }
```

Comment: You need to initialize the `imageLocation` array to the right size.

Comment: You didn't initialize your string of array ``String[] imageLocation = new String[x];``  is it?

Comment: Yes. It seems that way, I didn't initialize the string array that's the reason for NullPointerException. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
String[] imageLocation = new String[imagesSelected.length];
```

Otherwise `imageLocation` will be `null`.

By the way, you don't need the `if` around your loop. It's completely redundant, as that will be the same logic that will be used at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

imageLocation[i]

have you initialized imageLocation?

I believe this error is because you are trying to point to a location in the string array that does not exist. imageLocation[0,1,2,3...etc] do not exist yet because the string array has not been initialized.

Try String[] imageLocation[however long you want the array to be]

Answer (score 2):

You must allocate memory for imageLocation.

```
imageLocation = new String[LENGTH];
```

Comment: I solved my problem already. But still thank you for the answer and your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your final solution code should be like as below, or compiler will give you an error that `imageLocation` may not have been initialized

```
    String[] imageLocation = new String[imagesSelected != null ? imagesSelected.length : 0];

    if (imagesSelected.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesSelected.length; i++) {
            int start = imagesSelected[i].indexOf("WB/");
            imageLocation[i] = imagesSelected[i].substring(start + 3);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this code

```
String[] imageLocation;

        if(imagesSelected.length >0){
          imageLocation = new String[imageSelected.length];
        for(int i=0;i<imagesSelected.length;i++){
            int start = imagesSelected[i].indexOf("WB/");
            imageLocation[i] = imagesSelected[i].substring(start + 3);
        }
        }
```

Comment: I got it working already. Thanks for the answer and your time!